# purse env variable from nginx to vue

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx

As far as I search, there are several tips to place dynamic variables in `nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. 
 Instead, I want to activate env variable in apiURLs.js file, which will be loaded in vue files.

```
# apiURLs.js
export const apiUrls = {
    auth: "http://{{IP_ADDRESS}}:8826/auth/",
    service1: "http://{{IP_ADDRESS}}:8826/",
    service2: "http://{{IP_ADDRESS}}:8827/"
};
```

```
# in xxx.vue
let apiUrl = `${apiUrls.auth}login/`;
```

I tried `envsubst` in docker-compose.yml as

```
environment:
  - IP_ADDRESS
command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /code/src/apiUrls.js | tee /code/src/apiUrls.js && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

It appears to works as I go in docker container and confirmed that apiUrls.js is replaced.

However when I check the front app in browser and inspect api via chrome developer tool, it turned out that the api referred is still low url string with env argment, i.e. `http://%24%7Bip_address%7D:8826/auth/login`.

I suspect that vue project is pre-compiled during making docker image. 
Is there some solution?

Or is it possible to purse env variable declared in `nginx/conf.d/default.conf` to `apiURLs.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. Any js file will almost certainly get processed into a new bundled file by webpack during the vue build, as opposed to being loaded at runtime.

If you can navigate in your docker to the vue project and re-run the build, your env variables should update.

Check `package.json` in the vue project for different build options. You should get something like:

```yaml
{
  "name": "vue-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
//...
```

and be able to rebuild it with `npm run build`

(Also in the name of stating the obvious, remember to disable cache pages in the chrome dev tools when checking the updated site)

Comment: Thank you for the instruction! Do you mean I should replace docker-compose like 

`command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /code/src/apiUrls.js | tee /code/src/apiUrls.js && npm run build && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"`

Comment: Yeah if you can get those commands  to run sequentially it will work

Comment: so I think your command should be like so:  `command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /code/src/apiUrls.js | tee /code/src/apiUrls.js; npm run build && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"